# Does the initial_key have any crypto significance?

Tags: network

I created a genesis.json initial_key using very helpful instructions from [gensis.json initial key parameter: what is it?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/735/gensis-json-initial-key-parameter-what-is-it/787#787).

My question - does the initial key have any crypto significance or is it simply a hash for nodes to verify if they are properly on the same network?

Do I need to keep the private key generated for the initial_key safe? Does it have any use?

Answer (score 2):

When you starts a fresh blockchain with genesis.json, system account `eosio` is automatically generated with `initial_key`. `eosio` is the only one BP in this environment, and the signing key for block production becomes the given `initial_key`.

If you change `initial_key`, you also need to change the signing key used by nodeos when it produces a block. You can find `signature-provider` option from `config.ini` of nodeos. You can run nodeos like `nodeos --signature-provider=EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV=KEY:5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3` instead of putting this into `config.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Did some testing trying to make the initial_key something completely different than the initial signature-provider keypair and nodeos started throwing the following errors:

```
error 2020-06-06T07:36:25.001 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:1457      start_block          ] Not producing block because I don't have any private keys relevant to authority: [0,{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOSRandomInitialKey","weight":1}]}]
```

So through my initial findings, yes - that key is significant otherwise subsequent blocks cannot be added.

I'd still love for someone to answer the why or how it works.