# Is the default wallet must?

Tags: nodeos, accounts, wallet, keys

I am creating multiple node setup. When started to build EOS environment, this is one of the step https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/development-environment/create-development-wallet in documentation.

My first question is, do we need to create default wallet always whether it is for production setup or local development?

I created genesis node, in which **producer** is **eosio**, I have created wallet other than default, and provide signature provider key as newly generated keys. When I run blockchain its showing logs as:

```
error 2020-11-06T04:23:49.500 nodeos    producer_plugin.cpp:1393      start_block          ] Not producing block because I don't have any private keys relevant to authority: [0,{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS4v99brHWC5vc9Dsk4fvD9ZDhk8sfAnAqg5os51G8rJpDxknmr6","weight":1}]}]
```

Do I need to create default wallet and import keys in it to resolve this error?

Second question:

As per my understanding, the genesis node block producer should be **eosio** and generate other producer accounts for other nodes. Am I correct? Is it must to create a new block producer account for each node?

Please guide.

Edit:
The above error was generated because the `initial_key` in `genesis.json` was different than the genesis node key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to create a wallet for each node. It does not communicate with wallet at all.

You should set `producer-name` and `signature-provider` options for each block producing node. You need to create an account with the `producer-name` and set a pair of private and public key for sigining produced block. These keys don't need to same to those of owner or active permission, but when you register block producer by `eosio::regproducer`, you should call it with the key provided by signature-provider option.

Comment: Yes, I will not create wallet for each node but what about default wallet? Is it needed? I never run this command `cleos wallet create --to-console`  till now instead, created wallet providing name parameter.

Comment: No. Refer to [this](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5484/does-the-initial-key-have-any-crypto-significance).

Comment: Thank you @conr2d for the help and support.